# Uploading File to specific folder in Google drive in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, google-drive-api, angular5

I am trying to upload a file to a specific folder, but I am unable to do it.
Uploading is working correctly but it is not putting a file in a particular folder.

I am trying to do a Resumable upload with google drive rest version 3.

Assuming I already have a Folder ID.

First getting uploading URI :

```
uploadFileToDrive(name: string, content: string): Promise<Object> {
        const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable`;
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
        return this.http
            .post(url, { name: name, role: 'reader', type: 'anyone', 'parents': [{"id":parentId}] }, options)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => this.gDriveUploadFile(content, response.headers.get('location')));
    }
```

Second uploading media :

```
gDriveUploadFile(file, url): Promise<any> { //file and url we got from first func
        console.log(file + " "+ url );
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'X-Upload-Content-Type': file.type ,
        });

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

        return this.http.post(`${url}`, file, options) //call proper resumable upload endpoint and pass just file as body
            .toPromise()
    }
```

Also, I would like to know how I will be able to create a folder using google rest API in angular.

Comment: You are using Drive API v3. So how about modifying ``'parents': [{"id":parentId}]`` to ``'parents': [parentId]``? Then, when you want to create a folder, please use the endpoint of ``POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files`` and use the request body of ``{"name": "### folderName ###", "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}``. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Are you still following this issue? I solved it @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved and I could know my estimation was correct.